# sorting the values in a specific order Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, sorting, group-by, oracle12c

I have a table like below. How to sort the column key as F,W,H?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
select * from table1 where key in ('F','W','H')
order by case
when key ='F' then 1
when key ='W' then 2
else 3
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `case when` expression in `order by` clause

```
select * from tablename
order by case when key='F' then 1 when key='W' then 2 when key='H' then 3 end
```

Answer (score 0):

use decode

```
select a.* from yourtablename a
order by decode(Key,'F',1,'W',2,'H',3)
```

or

```
order by instr('FWH',Key)
```